# illegal start of declaration error with foreach

Tags: scala, foreach, apache-zeppelin

I want to show the distinct count of Column1 for each score_threshold; however, I am getting an "illegal start of declaration" error for this line:

```
results = results :+ (threshold,count)
```

I am trying to z.show() these counts on a graph in a Zeppelin notebook.

I have the following scala code:

```
val score_threshold = Seq(50.0,100.0,200.0,250.00,500.00,1000.00) 
var results = Seq((0.0,0.0)) 

    score_threshold.foreach(threshold:Double => {
        val counts = DF.filter($"score" >= threshold)
            .groupBy().agg(countDistinct("column1").as("count")).rdd.map(x=> x.getDouble(0)).collect.head
        results = results :+ (threshold,count)
        })
z.show(results.toDF("threshold","count"))
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
error: illegal start of declaration
        results = results :+ (threshold,count)
```

Comment: score_threshold is a sequence of strings not a seq of double. You have to read it as a string and cast each value to double.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ist possible that `val counts` should be `val count`?

When you use `()` in a foreach call you may only pass a simple expression as argument. To make your argument a simple expression you have to wrap threshold:Double also in `()`.

```
score_threshold.foreach( (threshold: Double) => {
  val counts = DF.filter($"score" >= threshold)
  .groupBy().agg(countDistinct("column1").as("count")).rdd.map(x=> x.getDouble(0)).collect.head
  results = results :+ (threshold,count)
}
```

If I may recommend a (imho) better variant. When you know the function you want to pass is not a simple expression, you should use `{}` after `foreach`.

```
score_threshold.foreach { threshold: Double =>
  val counts = DF.filter($"score" >= threshold) .groupBy().agg(countDistinct("column1").as("count")).rdd.map(x=> x.getDouble(0)).collect.head
  results = results :+ (threshold,count)
}
```

Just to be annoying (and without any knowladge of apache-zeppelin) I add a more functional alternative with `foldLeft` instead of using a `var`.

```
score_threshold.foldLeft(Seq((0.0,0.0))) {
  case (acc, next) =>
    val count = DF.filter($"score" >= next) .groupBy().agg(countDistinct("column1").as("count")).rdd.map(x=> x.getDouble(0)).collect.head
    acc :+ (next,count)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your second version: 

`val score_threshold = Seq(50.0,100.0,200.0,250.00,500.00,1000.00)
var results = Seq[(Double,Long)]()

    score_threshold.foreach { threshold: Double =>
     val count = DF
        .filter($"score" >= threshold)
        .groupBy().agg(countDistinct("column1").as("count")).rdd.map(x=> x.getLong(0)).collect.head
    results = results :+ (threshold,count)
    }

z.show(results.toDF("score_threshold","count"))`

Answer (score 0):

```
I was able to resolve the issue, but your solution is faster. 

val score_threshold = Seq(50.0,100.0,200.0,250.00,500.00,1000.00) 
var results = Seq[(Double,Double)]() 

score_threshold.foreach(threshold => { 
val count = Df.filter($"score" >= threshold).groupBy().agg(countDistinct("column1").as("count").cast(DoubleType)).rdd.map(x=> x.getDouble(0)).collect.head 

results = results :+ (threshold,count) }) 
z.show(results.toDF("score_threshold","count"))
```